# Galois Theory - Normal Basis

Tags: galois-theory

I am studying Galois Theory and have been given the following question:
Find a normal basis of $Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$.

I have found the Galois group to be:
$$
\alpha_1:\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt2, \sqrt3\mapsto\sqrt3\\
\alpha_2:\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt3, \sqrt3\mapsto\sqrt2\\
\alpha_3:\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2, \sqrt3\mapsto-\sqrt3\\
\alpha_4:\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt3, \sqrt3\mapsto-\sqrt2
$$

Is this correct?

I know what an orbit is and that a basis is said to be normal if it is a single orbit of the Galois group, but don't understand what is meant by $single$.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The extension is over the field $Q$ btw

Comment: A normal basis is one you get as the orbit of a single element $z\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Meaning that your task is to find an element $z$ such that the elements $\alpha_i(z)$, $i=1,2,3,4$, form a basis. Equivalently, $\alpha_i(z)$ are to be linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: BTW your automorphisms $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_4$ are wrong. You should have $\alpha(\sqrt2)=\pm\sqrt2$ and $\alpha(\sqrt3)=\pm\sqrt3$ for all automorphisms $\alpha$. All four sign combinations work here.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, Think I get it now!

Answer (score 3):

The Galois group contains the four automorphisms:

1. $p:a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6 \mapsto a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$
2. $q:a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6 \mapsto a-b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3-d\sqrt6$
3. $r:a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6 \mapsto a+b\sqrt2-c\sqrt3-d\sqrt6$
4. $s:a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6 \mapsto a-b\sqrt2-c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$

The Galois group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\Bbb Q)$ acts on $L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ in an obvious manner. The orbit of an element $x \in L$ is defined as $\{\varphi(x) \mid \varphi \in G\}$, denoted $\mathcal O(x)$.

Therefore, the question is asking you to find $x \in L$ such that $\operatorname{span}_\Bbb Q(\mathcal O(x)) = L$. Since $L$ has basis $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6\}$, one only need to check if those four basis elements are linear combinations of the orbit.

By inspection, let $x=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6$. Then:

- $1 = \frac14p(x) + \frac14q(x) + \frac14r(x) + \frac14s(x)$
- $\sqrt2 = \frac14p(x) - \frac14q(x) + \frac14r(x) - \frac14s(x)$
- $\sqrt3 = \frac14p(x) + \frac14q(x) - \frac14r(x) - \frac14s(x)$
- $\sqrt6 = \frac14p(x) - \frac14q(x) - \frac14r(x) + \frac14s(x)$

Therefore, $\mathcal O(x)$ is a normal basis of $L$.

---

An equivalent condition is that $(p(x),q(x),r(x),s(x))$ be linearly independent.

Taking $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6\}$ as basis, we write $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt4$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d\end{bmatrix}^\top$.

Then, writing each element in $(p(x),q(x),r(x),s(x))$ as a row, we obtain the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a&b&c&d \\ a&-b&c&-d \\ a&b&-c&-d \\ a&-b&-c&d \end{bmatrix}$$

Which we rewrite as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&1 \\ 1&-1&1&-1 \\ 1&1&-1&-1 \\ 1&-1&-1&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a&0&0&0 \\ 0&b&0&0 \\ 0&0&c&0 \\ 0&0&0&d \end{bmatrix}$$

whose determinant is $16abcd$.

It satisfies our condition iff $16abcd\ne0$, which is iff $abcd\ne0$, which is iff none of $a,b,c,d$ is $0$.

So, any $x = a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$ works as long as $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are all non-zero.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense thanks! Out of interest, what would the Galois group of say $F_2\subset F_8$ be?

Comment: @J.Menton $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ generated by the Frobenius automorphism $f:z \mapsto z^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Your field is biquadratic, with Galois group $C_2\times C_2$ (and you wrote it down explicitly). As was stressed by Jyrki Lahtonen, a normal basis will consist of the conjugates of a single element. Just try $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3$

EDIT : I made an error of computation, I shouldn't work too early in the morning ! It is obvious that $\sqrt 6$ cannot be obtained as a $\mathbf Q$-linear combination of the conjugates of $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3$, although this is a primitive element of the biquadratic extension.